# Help in tracking a stalker

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy, instagram

My wife is being harassed on Facebook and Instagram. The messages are coming from fake names and when she blocks them, they just make another account and keep sending other things. Is there any way to figure out who is really sending them or where they are coming from? Are there any way of tracking things like this?

Please someone help us.

Answer (score 1):

It is not easy to track all this for a normal users. Here are few steps you can follow to prevent abuse:

- You can report this to local police
- You can follow the steps as suggested by Facebook - [What should I do if I'm being bullied, harassed or attacked by someone on Facebook?](https://www.facebook.com/help/116326365118751)
- Learn about [Abuse Resource](https://www.facebook.com/help/726709730764837)
- Follow these instructions on Instagram - [Reporting harassment or bullying on Instagram](https://www.facebook.com/help/instagram/547601325292351)